# Inequality involving an integral of the cumulative distribution function of the Gaussian

Tags: self-study, distributions, normal-distribution

Show that:
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left((2-2F(x))^2-1\right)\mathrm{d}x\geq 0$, where $F(x)$ is the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution.

Can anyone give some pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: Check out [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). You might want to add the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag.

Comment: have you drawn the integrand

Comment: I think the integral over the half line $(-\infty, 0)$ is $-\infty$, and over the line $(0, \infty)$ it's $\infty$, so the Lebesgue integral does not even exist ... you probably want something like $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n$ instead of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Due to the substantial change in the integral during the edits, this question looks like it doesn't reflect any research.  Notice that when $x\le 1$, $F(x) \le F(-1) \lt 1/5$.  Therefore $((2-2F(x))^2 \gt 4(1-1/5)^2 = 64/25$ for all $x \le -1$, implying the integral from $-n$ to $-1$ exceeds $64(n-1)/25$ for all $n\gt 1$. *Consequently your integral diverges.*  What, then, are you really trying to ask??

Answer (score 2):

Several integrals involving Gaussian functions and its cdf [are well referenced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions). Since the expression involves a square, perhaps starting with expressions like:

$$ \int F (x)^{2}\,dx=xF (x)^{2}+2F (x)\phi (x)-{\frac {1}{\sqrt {\pi }}}F \left(x{\sqrt {2}}\right)+C$$

may give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so as I said in the comment, the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ doesn't really make sense, so I'm going to work with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n$.

Taking $y = -x$ we have:
$$
\int_{-n}^n (2 - 2F(x))^2 - 1 dx = \int_{-n}^n 4F(y)^2 - 1 dy
$$
Now renaming $y$ on the right hand side of the equation as $x$, and avaraging those two things together we get:
$$
\int_{-n}^n ((2 - 2F(x))^2 - 1) dx = \int_{-n}^n 2(1 - F(x))^2 + 2F(x)^2 - 1 dx
$$
And now from $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} \geq (\frac{a+b}{2})^2$ we get :
$$
2 (1-F(x))^2 + 2F(x)^2 \geq 4 \left(\frac{(1 - F(x)) + F(x)}{2}\right)^2 = 1
$$
So the integral is positive for all $n$.